# Trying to fuse row when with same "name"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

In SQL I am trying  to get two rows to fuse when their name is the same.

Right now I have a SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT TABLE.Name, SUM(TABLE.Value) AS VALUE1, 0 AS VALUE2
FROM TABLE
WHERE TABLE.Bool = true
GROUP BY TABLE.Name

SELECT TABLE.Name, 0 AS VALUE1, SUM(TABLE.Value)  AS VALUE2
FROM TABLE
WHERE TABLE.Bool = false
GROUP BY TABLE.Name
```

Which give me a result lookin like this :

```
|Name    |Value1    |Value2  |
------------------------------
|Name1   |1000      |0       |
|Name2   |2000      |0       |
|Name3   |3000      |0       |

|Name    |Value1    |Value2  |
------------------------------
|Name1   |0         |0001    |
|Name2   |0         |0002    |
|Name3   |0         |0003    |
```

Using the UNION operator would yield a result such as this:

```
|Name    |Value1    |Value2  |
------------------------------
|Name1   |1000      |0       |
|Name2   |2000      |0       |
|Name3   |3000      |0       |
|Name1   |0         |0001    |
|Name2   |0         |0002    |
|Name3   |0         |0003    |
```

The result I'd like to obtain is something like this:

```
|Name    |Value1    |Value2  |
------------------------------
|Name1   |1000      |0001    |
|Name2   |2000      |0002    |
|Name3   |3000      |0003    |
```

**Note :**

Due to the way the table is built, both selects can return a different number of rows.

**A bit of precision about the construction of the table :**

1. The displayed column Value1 and Value 2 both come from the same column, of the same table, and use the same dataset. The only difference is that sometime a condition is met and other time not.
2. The table can have several fields with the same name, but we want to display only one result for each name.
3. I cannot modify the table, or its structure in any way, shape or form, even if I think the structure could be improved a lot.

If anyone knows of a way to do this, it would help a lot.

Comment: You're gonna need to add the tag of the sql language you are interested in.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Oops, srry forgot to do it, gonna change that right now, thanks :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT TABLE.Name, 
       SUM(case when TABLE.Bool = true then TABLE.Value else 0 end) AS VALUE1,
       SUM(case when TABLE.Bool = false then TABLE.Value else 0 end) AS VALUE2
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY TABLE.Name
```

`VALUE1` returns the sum of `Value` when the condition is met, whereas `VALUE2` returns the sum of `Value` for the rest of the records.

Comment: Thanks it's working ! I tried it earlier, but couldn't figure out the way to make it work.